# Escaping characters within Applescript copiedtext

Tags: applescript

I have the following AppleScript. When ran it copies the currently highlighted text in a browser window and takes that copied text and passes it in a curl to POST API. The only issue is that if the highlighted text contains special characters such as '(' then it fails, with the unexpected token.

How would I correctly escape the copiedtext?

```
on run {input, parameters}


-- Takes current highlighted work and passes as variable to bot api, which then adds it to the DB of highlights for processing. 

delay 3
tell application "Google Chrome"
    set theURL to (get URL of active tab of window 1)
    set pgTitl to (get title of active tab of front window)
end tell


activate application "Google Chrome"

tell application "System Events"
    keystroke "c" using command down
    delay 0.5
    set copiedtext to the clipboard
end tell

set x to do shell script "curl -F text='" & copiedtext & "' -F color=blue -F source_url=" & theURL & " -F source_id=" & theURL & " -F source_title=" & theURL & " https://www.website.com/api/v1/?token=xxxxxxxxxxxxx"


display notification "Complete." with title " Highlight " subtitle "Highlight"

return input
end run
```

Comment: Try changing `copiedtext` in your `curl` command to `quoted form of copiedtext `. This may help in some cases however you might have to process the text to escape shell special characters with a backslash before passing it to the `do shell script` command. Just a though off the top of my head and haven't tested and why posting as a comment, not an answer.

Comment: What about Applescript objevtive c? if you'd use that theres plenty of possibilities to sanitize strings